# Bash/xargs: How to mass assign user privileges?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rights

I have created a new user. My current user obviously has the following rights:

```
$ groups
max adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

Where `max` is the name of the current user account.

I tried paramer expansion but the output of `${groups}` is empty, so I just piped groups to `xargs`

```
$ groups | xargs -I _ sudo usermod -aG _ new_user_name
```

I get the error message that there is no folder `max adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare` because obviously the output of `groups` is not splitted by whitespace.

But as I said `${groups}` is empty, so there is nothing I could pipe to xargs.

Second try:

```
my_arr=(adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare)

$ echo ${my_arr[@]} | xargs -I _ usermod -aG _ new_user_name
```

The arguments of the array don't get splitted even though I **don't** put the parameter expansion in double quotes.

xargs treats the piped arguments still as one big string `adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare`

What's the right solution?

Comment: You're using `/bin/sh`??? Arrays are a Bash feature, not POSIX `sh`.

Comment: To somewhat expand on the previous comment, you need to use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` (or not use an array, and figure out a different approach). See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit, since it distracts from the main question and is covered by a common FAQ.

Comment: Okay, my fault. I am very sorry for my error. The script of iBug worked with `#!/bin/bash`. Thanks for your efforts. I am just a beginner with working with the shell. Thanks for pointing me to `"Difference between sh and bash"` I will read and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usermod` adds one or more users to **one group** at a time, so you'll have to use a loop:

```
for g in "${my_arr[@]}"; do
  usermod -aG "$g" new_user_name
done
```

Note that `xargs` by default uses as many arguments as possible in one invocation of the supplied command, so if you go with `xargs`, limit the number of arguments consumed to one at a time (`-n 1`):

```
echo "${my_arr[@]}" | xargs -n 1 -I _ usermod -aG _ new_user_name
```

Comment: So I would have to put a `\n` or something at the end of each array string? Btw: Why isn't producing ${groups} any output ? Thanks

Comment: @vonspotz No you don't add newlines manually. Using a loop is about as good as you can go. BTW: Use `$(groups)` to capture output of commands, not expanding variables.

Comment: I have edited my original post. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but still the same error message `usermod: the group »max adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare« doesn't exist`

Comment: @vonspotz Please edit your question to include the exact command you ran so we can take a look.

Comment: Notice that `"${my_arr[@]}"` is a Bash feature which is not compatible with `sh`.

Comment: The followup question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589593/bash-copying-files-with-xargs-why-do-i-get-this-returned-as-the-last-argument/67589819#67589819 solves the remaining problem.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial problem is that you need to tell `xargs` to read one argument at a time.

Less crucially, you probably don't want to include `max` in the input to `usermod`.

```sh
groups |
# Trim away first token (max)
sed 's/^[^ ]* //' |
# Pass to xargs with -n 1
xargs -n 1 -I _ sudo usermod -aG _ new_user_name
```

On Linux you may need to add `--delimiter ' '` to the `xargs` command line.

Comment: Yes, right, group `max` shouldn't be included, but I thought I would stifle the problem of adding to user group `max` until the rest would at least be working. Also I can remove one group manually, but I don't see why I shouldn't use bash to add the set of groups in general.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use Bash. I'm saying don't use Bash features if you are _actually_ using `sh`. But this answer does not try to use arrays or other Bash features so it should work fine with either.

Comment: I'm sorry but still the same error message as below :( It just doesn't split the arguments as it actually should. What else would the purpose of xargs be.

Comment: On Linux you may need to add `--delimiter ' '` and perhaps `-r`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use xargs -i flag. This will split up your string and in your next statement, you can access each token using `{}`. This will run the sudo command for each of the groups.

So try

`groups | xargs -i  sudo usermod -aG {} new_user_name`

Comment: Don't know what's wrong but it still complains that the group `max adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare` doesn't exist. Thanks for your reply though !

Comment: Ok, try  -I (capital i) instead of -i which is now deprecated.

Comment: `Group {} doesn't exist.` Jesus, I really don't know what's going wrong here

Comment: `-i` is just a convenience for `-I {}` which is similar to what you are already doing. This is a red herring.