# Bash: Copying files with xargs. Why do I get this returned as the last argument by xargs?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have copied some files from one user-account to a new one by these commands

```
$ folders_array=(.mozilla .thunderbird .ssh .eclipse)

$ echo ${folders_array[@]} | xargs -d " " -I _ sudo cp -r _ /home/nebukadnexa/
```

I can't explain the form of the last argument `.eclipse` which is, that it is `'.eclipse'$'\n'` and thus wasn't found in my current home directory and thus also wasn't copied of course.

Can you point me to how xargs produces the argument `'.eclipse'$'\n'` (being the last argument)?

EDIT: Maybe a better solution than `-d " "` is `tr " " "\n"` ?

```
echo ${folders_array[@]} | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I _ printf "%s\n" _
```

Comment: Why are you using `-d " "`? By default xargs treats any whitespace as a delimiter.

Comment: @Barmar It's not reliably portabde to assume that; see the OP's earlier question today.

Comment: @Barmar Normally it should if you don't put the parameter expansion of the array into double quotes. But look at this thread of mine where it doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67584696/bash-xargs-how-to-mass-assign-user-privileges

Comment: The hack proposed in your edit exacerbates the existing problem; you now can't support fileenames with spaces in them even if you fix the quoting. IMHO, a move in the wrong direction.

Comment: @tripleee `-d` is also not POSIX, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html. As far as I can tell from that, unquoted spaces should be treated as argument delimiters.

Comment: The problem you're having in your previous question is that `usermod` only allows you to specify one group at a time, but `xargs` tries to put them all in the same command unless you use `-n 1`.

Comment: It's the difference between `echo "${array[@]}" | xargs echo` and `echo "${array[@]}" | xargs -n 1 echo`

Comment: I see the other problem: When you use `-I _`, the `_` in the input is substituted as a single argument. The spaces lose their significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `-I _`, it replaces `_` as a single argument. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html) specifies this (emphasis mine):

> **-I *replstr***
> Insert mode: *utility* is executed for each line from standard input, **taking the entire line as a single argument**, inserting it in *arguments* for each occurrence of *replstr*.

This is why the GNU `cp -t` extension is useful. It allows you to put the files to copy at the end of the command, which is where `xargs` puts them by default, without combining them into a single argument.

```
echo "${folders_array[@]}" | xargs sudo cp -r -t /home/nebukadnexa/
```

Note that piping to `xargs` won't work if any of the filenames contain whitespace.

Comment: Hello Barmar, couldn't I use the `-n` option on xargs to feign off `combining them into a single argument.` ? And doesn't putting the parameter-expansion `${folders_array[@]}` in double quotes (according to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26672/440130 in this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/what-is-word-splitting-why-is-it-important-in-shell-programming) also prevent `field splitting`, thus lumping all arguments together in one singular string ? Cheers !

Comment: Yes to the first question, no to the second.

Comment: When you put quotes around an array with `[@]`, it requotes each array element, not the whole array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Comment: But if you use `-n 1` you lose the benefit of running a single `cp` command for all the files.

Comment: What do I have to do to compensate?

Comment: Do it as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you set `-d " "` the newline at the end of the `echo` output is considered part of the data, not a delimiter.

The absolutely simplest fix is to not provide the input on a single line. (Notice also the fixed quoting of the array.)

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${folders_array[@]}" |
xargs -r sudo cp -t -r /home/nebukadnexa/
```

I also switched to `cp -t` which exists precisely so that you can simplify cases like this. This is a GNU extension, so it's not necessarily portable to non-Linux platforms (though it's not hard to write your own reimplementation, either).

If you need to support completely arbitrary file names (even file names which contain newlines), `printf '%s\0'` piped to `xargs -0` is good to know, though again, that's a GNU extension.

Comment: Wouldn't be in this case sufficient to do just a `echo ${folders_array[@]} | xargs _ sudo cp -r _ /home/nebukadnexa/`

Comment: `xargs` will still treat whitespace in the filenames as argument delimiters.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${folders_array[@]}"` nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I see the benefit of `xargs` here anyway.

```
for d in .mozilla .thunderbird .ssh .eclipse
do sudo cp -r "$d" /home/nebukadnexa/
done
```